# Getting the translated string inside the script - Vue JS + Vue Translate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have something like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ text }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      text: 'Hello world'
    })
  }
</script>
```

I want to get the translated string for "Hello world" inside script tag but I don't know how to do that. I tried something like:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      text: t('hello_world')
    })
  }
</script>
```

This `t('hello_world')` would bring the translated string for me from another file with the translated strings mapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use Vue external functions like you did. Here is a short working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  data: {
    text: t('hello_world')
  }
})

function t(text) {
  return 'Hello World' // simulate output for demonstration purposes
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  {{ text }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use    [Vue-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n), it can solve you problem.